# How to add icons in dc.js piechart slices instead texts

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have been working with dc.js for a year now. Recently I have been tasked to implement a pie chart as below:

[image: user requirement image]

I want to replace the text labels in the pie chart slices with appropriate images.

I saw this implemented in pure d3.js. Can someone help me translate the implementation to dc.js?

http://jsfiddle.net/LLwr4q7s/

```
pie
    .width(600)
    .height(500)
    .radius(200)
    .innerRadius(120)
    .dimension(disastersDimension)
    .group(disastersGroup)
    .on("filtered", function (chart, filter) {
      var sel = filter;
      let percentage = 0,
        value = 0;
      let disastersBuffer = [];
      totalAmount = 0;

      pie.selectAll("text.pie-slice").text((d) => {
        percentage = dc.utils.printSingleValue(
          ((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2 * Math.PI)) * 100
        );
        disastersBuffer.push({ ...d.data, percentage });
        totalAmount += parseFloat(d.data.value);
      });

      filterPiechart(sel, percentage, totalAmount, disastersBuffer, value);
    })
    .on("renderlet", (chart) => {
      if (!chart.selectAll("g.selected")._groups[0].length) {
        chart.filter(null);
        filterPiechart("", 100, totalAmount, [], 0);
      }
      var arc = chart.radius(250).innerRadius(100);
      console.log(arc);
      var g = chart.selectAll(".pie-slice");

      chart
        .selectAll(".pie-slice")
        .append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "img/disasters/Floods.png")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-10,10) rotate(315)")
        .attr("width", "26px")
        .attr("hight", "26px")
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
          var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
          return bbox.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function () {
          var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
          return bbox.y;
        });

      g.append("g")
        .append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
          let filteredImage = self.piedata.find(
            (i) => i.label == d.data.key
          );
          let image = filteredImage ? filteredImage.image : "";
          return image;
        })
        .attr("width", 30)
        .attr("height", 40)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
          var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
          return bbox.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
          return bbox.y;
        });
    })
    .addFilterHandler(function (filters, filter) {
      filters.length = 0; // empty the array
      filters.push(filter);
      return filters;
    });
```

Comment: Images are not a good option. You can use SVG icons (Here is an exaple of SVG icon set: https://iconstore.co/icons/weather-icon-set/) - just take an appropriate `<path>` from the icon set and put it instead of `<image>`

Comment: thanks @MichaelRovinsky, i will try that...but if you don't mind you can share me small piece of code i can use. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, apologies for an incomplete example, but I ran out of time and I think this shows the principles.

1. I agree with @MichaelRovinsky that SVG icons would be better than images, but I couldn't find a CDN for SVG icons that would be suitable for the example, and I think the principles are exactly the same, since you could embed SVGs as `image` just as well.
2. Using placeimg.com for this purpose leads to weird results because the same URL will yield different results when read twice, so e.g. two slices may end up with the same image, and images change when the chart redraws.

Luckily these are both beside the point of customizing dc.js!

#### Adding things to dc.js pie slices

It [would be nice](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1833) if dc.js used an svg `g` group element to put the text in. Then we could just add to it and the position would be correct.

Instead, we have to add our `image` element and read the corresponding data from the pie label to get the placement:

```
  chart.on('pretransition', chart => {
    let labelg = chart.select('g.pie-label-group');
    let data = labelg.selectAll('text.pie-label').data();
    console.log('data', data);
```

Then we can add `image` elements in the same layer/g:

```
    let pieImage = labelg.selectAll('image.pie-image');
    let arcs = chart._buildArcs();
    pieImage.data(data)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append('image')
                    .attr('class', 'pie-image')
                    .attr('x', -19) 
                    .attr('y', -19))
       .attr('href', d => images[d.data.key === 'Others' ? 'Others' : d.data.key.slice(4)])
       .attr('transform', d => chart._labelPosition(d, arcs));
  });
```

Notice that the attributes which only need to be set once (on enter) are inside the join call, and the attributes which need to be set every redraw (on update) are outside the join call.

`x` and `y` are negative one half the image size to center the images.

I used an object to store the URLs but you could use whatever.

[image: pie with images]

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/teqvbnu6/60/)

#### Limitation

As with any customization of the pie chart, this doesn't account for animations well. The images will move before the animation is complete. If you care, I think I wrote an answer some years ago which dealt with this properly. I can probably dig it up but it was quite complicated and IMHO not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

I took the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLwr4q7s/) and added a couple of 'Meteoicons' I found [here](https://www.alessioatzeni.com/meteocons/).

(*Of course, those icons are taken as an example and I have no permission to use them commercially*)

The icons are stored in a separated `<svg>` elements. To render an icon, just select its root `<g>` element and copy its content to another `<g>` you create in your piechart:

```js
g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${arc.centroid(d)}) scale(0.25)`)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-256,-256)') // The original icons are 256 x 256
  .html(d => d3.select(`#meteo-icon-${... some attribute of d ...} > g`).html())
```

The code is for demonstration purposes only, you will need to modify it for your needs.

See the result in the snippet below:

```js
var width = 550,
    height = 550,
    radius = 250,
    colors = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(['#336699 ','#336699 ','#ACD1E9','#ACD1E9','#ACD1E9']);

var image_width=40,
    image_height=40;

var piedata = [
    {
        label: "test",
        image: "http://placeimg.com/40/40/any",
        value: 50 
    },
    {   
        label: "",
        image: "http://placeimg.com/42/42/any",
        value: 50
    },
    {   
        label: "Jonathan",
        image: "http://placeimg.com/44/44/any",
        value: 50
    },
    {   
        label: "Lorenzo",
        image: "http://placeimg.com/46/46/any",
        value: 50
    },
    {   
        label: "Hillary",
        image: "http://placeimg.com/38/38/any",
        value: 50
    }
  ]


var pie = d3.layout.pie()
     .value(function(d) {
     return d.value;
  })

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
   .outerRadius(250)
   .innerRadius(100)

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate('+(width-radius)+','+(height-radius)+')');


var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(piedata))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d,i) { return colors(i); });

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${arc.centroid(d)}) scale(0.25)`)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(-256,-256)')
  .html(() => d3.select(`#meteo-icon-${Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2} > g`).html())
.selectAll('path')
.style('fill', 'orange');
```

```css
path {
 stroke: #fff;
 fill-rule: evenodd;
}

text {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.meteo-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="meteo-icon-1" class="meteo-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <g>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#1D1D1B" d="M177.615,288c7.438-36.521,39.688-64,78.396-64
            c38.709,0,70.958,27.479,78.376,64h32c-7.834-54.125-54.084-96-110.376-96c-56.271,0-102.541,41.875-110.375,96H177.615z
             M256.011,160c8.833,0,16-7.167,16-16v-32c0-8.833-7.167-16-16-16c-8.832,0-16,7.167-16,16v32
            C240.011,152.833,247.179,160,256.011,160z M403.073,156.917c-6.249-6.25-16.374-6.25-22.625,0l-22.625,22.625
            c-6.249,6.25-6.249,16.375,0,22.625c6.251,6.25,16.376,6.25,22.625,0l22.625-22.625
            C409.323,173.292,409.323,163.167,403.073,156.917z M154.177,179.542l-22.625-22.625c-6.249-6.25-16.373-6.25-22.625,0
            c-6.249,6.25-6.249,16.375,0,22.625l22.625,22.625c6.252,6.25,16.376,6.25,22.625,0
            C160.429,195.917,160.429,185.792,154.177,179.542z M352.011,320h-192c-8.832,0-16,7.167-16,16s7.168,16,16,16h192
            c8.833,0,16-7.167,16-16S360.844,320,352.011,320z M320.011,384h-128c-8.832,0-16,7.167-16,16s7.168,16,16,16h128
            c8.833,0,16-7.167,16-16S328.844,384,320.011,384z"/>
    </g>
</svg>


<svg id="meteo-icon-2" class="meteo-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<g>
<path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M349.852,343.15c-49.876,49.916-131.083,49.916-181,0c-49.916-49.917-49.916-131.125,0-181.021
    c13.209-13.187,29.312-23.25,47.832-29.812c5.834-2.042,12.293-0.562,16.625,3.792c4.376,4.375,5.855,10.833,3.793,16.625
    c-12.542,35.375-4,73.666,22.249,99.917c26.209,26.228,64.501,34.75,99.917,22.25c5.792-2.062,12.271-0.583,16.625,3.792
    c4.376,4.333,5.834,10.812,3.771,16.625C373.143,313.838,363.06,329.941,349.852,343.15z M191.477,184.754
    c-37.438,37.438-37.438,98.354,0,135.771c40,40.021,108.125,36.417,143-8.167c-35.959,2.25-71.375-10.729-97.75-37.084
    c-26.375-26.354-39.333-61.771-37.084-97.729C196.769,179.796,194.039,182.192,191.477,184.754z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am very thankful for your very detailed explanation however I am looking for dc.js related implementation of what you have explained that's why I shared some of pure d3.js fiddle solutions for people to help in translating the specific piece of code that implements that to dc.js code. I am not looking for the whole implementation but how can I put an image or svg icon on piechart slices with dc.js

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you talk about, but if there is another suitable solution that works for you, use it. If my answer is good enough, I will appreciate if you mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and time. Hope others who have knowledge in dc.js will pick it from your answer.